# Assigning values to a matrix through vector addition from an adjacency matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinatorics, adjacency-matrix, matrix-indexing

Very new to Matlab, I usually use STATA.

I want to use the nchoosek fuction to get the sum of vectors in one matrix.

I have a 21x21 adjacency matrix, with either 0 or 1 as the inputs. I want to create a new matrix, that will give me a sum of inputs between all possible triads from the adjacency matrix.

The new matrix should look have four variables, indexes (i, j, k) - corresponding to each combination from the 21x21. And a final variable which is a sum of the inputs.

The code I have so far is:

```
C = nchoosek(21,3)
B = zeros(nchoosek(21,3), 4)
for i=1:C
    for j=i+1:C
        for k=j+1:C
            B(?)=B(i, j, k, A(i)+A(j)+A(k)) #A is the 21x21 adj mat
        end
    end
end
```

I know my assignment statement is incorrect as I don't completed understand the indexing role of the ":" operator. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to sum all possible triad rows or columns? Or do you want to sum all possible combinations of the 441 elements in your matrix? An example with a smaller matrix will make this question clearer

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```
clear all
close all
clc

A = rand(21,21); % Replace this with actual A
rowNum = 0;
for i=1:21
    for j=i+1:21
        for k=j+1:21
            rowNum = rowNum+1;
            B(rowNum,:) = [i, j, k, sum(A(:,i)+A(:,j)+A(:,k))];
        end
    end
end
```

There are some points:

- You loop for different combinations. the total number of combination is `nchoosek(21,3)` which you can check after 3 nested loop. Your code with `for i=1:C` was the first error since you're actually looping for different values of `i` and different values of `j` and `k`. So these just 21 values not more.
- To avoid repeated combinations, it's enough to start new index after the previous one, which you've realized in your code.
- There are other possible approaches such as vectorized format, but to stick to your approach, I used a counter: rowNum which is the loop counter and updated along the loop.
- B(rowNum,:) means all element of rowNum'th row of the matrix B.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an  algorithm to find the triads in an adjacency matrix. It checks all possible triads and sums the values.

```
%basic adjacency matrix with two triads (1-2-5) (2-3-5)
A=[];
A(1,:) = [0 1 0 0 1];
A(2,:) = [1 0 1 0 1];
A(3,:) = [0 1 0 0 1];
A(4,:) = [0 0 0 0 1];
A(5,:) = [1 1 1 1 0];
A=A==1; %logical matrix

triads=nchoosek(1:5,3);
S=nan(size(triads,1),4);
for ct = 1:size(triads,1)
    S(ct,1:3)=[A(triads(ct,1),triads(ct,2)),A(triads(ct,1),triads(ct,3)),A(triads(ct,2),triads(ct,3))];
    S(ct,4)=sum(S(ct,1:3));
end
triads(find(S(:,4)==3),:)
```

`ans =`

```
 1     2     5
 2     3     5
```